# Portfolio Credit Risk

Tags: portfolio-management, risk, correlation, credit-risk

I need a portfolio credit risk model that takes into account the correlation between sectors. Models such as KMV, CreditRisk+ and CreditMetrics may be to computational expensive so I need some suggestions about a more "simple" portfolio credit risk model.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Why not run Monte Carlo simulation to simulate the loss distribution that considers default correlations? If I recall correctly, you should be able to do one with Merton's.